How do I format a footnote if I cite, for example, ten pages but I want to highlight one page in particular
I remember seeing people use the word “especially” or a contraction of it in some footnotes to denote that a certain page is more important than the others that are cited.
Would it look like: 1. Author, Book (City: Publisher, Year), pp.1-10, esp. p.5.
or
. . . pp.1-10, especially p.5
or something else?

The Chicago Manual of Style (2017) contains a few examples of this type, especially the following one, given in section 14.43:


For an extended discussion of Weber's program see M. N. Wise, "German Concepts of Force, Energy, and the Electromagnetic Ether, 1845-1880," in Conceptions of Ether; Studies in the History of Ether Theories, 1740-1900, G. N. Cantor and M. J. S. Hodge (eds.) (Cambridge: Cam­bridge Univ. Press, 1981), 269-307, esp. 276-83.


